# ValueError: Layer conv2d_41 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. All inputs to the layer should be tensors

Tags: keras, keras-layer, transfer-learning

I try transfer learning with custom input of backbone:

(I can not transfer learning normally because my input shape is N*N*8, so I need add small network_1 to reach N*N*3)

```
model_1 
   |
   |
add model_2
   |
add some layer
```

My code:

model_1.add(model_2)

model_1 is my small network:
model_2 is Mobilenet or VGG16, or Densenet .....

```
model_1 = Sequential()
model_1.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(size, size, F), name="InputLayer"))
model_1.add(Convolution2D(3, 128, padding = 'same'))

from keras.applications.densenet import DenseNet169
model_2=DenseNet169(weights='imagenet',include_top=False)

model_2.layers.pop(0) # remove input_layer of model_2 
model_1.add(model_2) # output model_1 is input model_2?

model_1 = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(model_1)
model_1 = Dropout(0.2)(model_1)
model_1 = Dense(256*256, activation='softmax')(model_1)
model_1 = Reshape(256, 256)(model_1)
```

I got errors:

```
ValueError: Layer global_average_pooling2d_3 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'keras.engine.sequential.Sequential'>. Full input: [<keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x7f74f6621d68>]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.
```

What wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Global Average Pooling 2D is a layer that performs an operation on a tensor, or multi-dimensional array. Therefore, passing a model architecture like DenseNet throws an error because the model has no idea what it's looking at. Model Architecture files are totally different from tensors.

To achieve what I think you're trying to achieve, run DenseNet and then pass the *output* of DenseNet into the model you're creating, instead of passing the model itself. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Do you mean code like:
```
model_2.layers.pop(0) # remove input_layer of model_2 
model_1.add(model_2)
```
after that
```
model  = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(model_1.output)
```

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. Removing the popping command should fix it. Please mark as correct if it helps!

Comment: Sorry, I looked it up online and saw that other models worked fine without popping off the first layer.

Comment: uh, but my input have more than 3 dimensions (N*N*8), so, i need small network (network_1) to reach 3  dimensions before transfer learning. 
network_.output is input of network_2